# Why are the black colored clothes avoided when visiting temple?

Tags: worship, temple, color

Why is that black color clothes are avoided or not allowed to wear in some temples?

They are also avoided when Hindus celebrate festivals like Diwali, Navratri etc, generally on auspicious days

I know that our temples don't allow belts, wallets etc when they are made of animal skin but whats wrong in wearing black clothes or having black colored objects with us?

Comment: I have seen in some temples where only black colored clothes are allowed like Ayyaappa swami and Lord Shani temples.

Comment: @Mr_Green Yes, I've seen tamils wearing but I'm Vaishnav and we don't wear black clothes on auspicious days

Comment: @all I don't think so, We are north Indian, I have never heard about this.

Comment: Black color indicates only ignorance and it is not inauspicious at all. This is a wrong belief borrowed and does not belong to Hindu philosophy. We bring in black color to ward off evil - make a small black bindi on the face also. Add one black color bangle during auspicious ceremony etc. - Malathi

Comment: Black is an auspicious colour for hindus. In kattil temple you get black bangles as prasad.In so many shrines, goddesses are wrapped up in places black with shades of red saries. Now after the influence of christianity, black is frowned upon. In fact for the ancient hindu women, black was the colour of krishna and was auspicious, while white was inauspicious. Wearing a pure white sari is frowned upon, unless one is a widow.

Comment: @Mr. Alien. Black color is considered as a symbol of tamo guna. So we don't wear it while going to a temple. But in sastras, it is stated that on every day of week, a different color should be wore. Saturday is for black color.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Some astrologival scriptures advice us to wear specific clothes to please deities of respective planets. I am not sure what exactly they are. I heard it in a talk by a scholar.

Comment: @SreeCharan Fine. I also hear them on TV. I just thought you knew. Well, they say- Monday- white or sky blue, Tuesday- Red, yellow or orange, Wednesday- Green or yellow, Thursday- Yellow or saffron, Friday- Red, white, Saturday- Black, blue, Sunday- White, Red, Yellow or Orange. I think they are right on this thing, as it also psychologically also provides us benefits. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Black is the symbol of unhappiness. That's why, we don't wear it in temples. Although, some *murtis* in temples are normally black, like that of *Shiva*. This is because Gods and Goddesses are free from happiness and unhappiness.

Above all, its just a symbol. (You can think of it as another superstition...)

In Hinduism, we have a lot of colors symbolizing things. Below are a few others:

- Red indicates both sensuality and purity.
- Saffron indicates sacred and holy things.
- Green indicates festive season and happiness.
- Yellow indicates knowledge and learning.
- White is a mixture of seven different colors hence it symbolizes a little bit of the quality of each.
- Blue is a symbol of nature; the sky, the oceans, the rivers and the lakes.

Comment: A point I missed about Lord Shani is (rightly) added by a commenter and another answerer. Yes, black coloured is favoured by Lord Shani. It is also favoured by the Lord of Mountains.

Comment: What is this- White is mixture of all colors, so it represents all. Saffron is mixture of Red and yellow, so does saffron mean- Sensuality and knowledge?

Comment: "Black is the symbol of unhappiness" so it is tradition and not religious by nature?

Answer (score 7):

Black is considered bad and evil. It is avoided in anything cultural, not just visiting temples.

However note that black is not completely avoided, people visiting [Sabarimala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabarimala) temple actually wear black colour. It is favourite colour of [Shani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shani) and people wear it to please him.