# Why Black clothes are not permissible while going to worship our Kulaswamini Ashapuri Devi?

Tags: belief

Since our childhood, my parents were not purchasing any black coloured cloths for us. When asked why it is so?

They said, Black colour clothes should be avoided because wearing them is not acceptable to our Kulaswamini Ashapuri Devi.

Can any body elaborate why is it so?

Comment: Any more info about this Devi? Is she your Kula Devi? In general, black clothes are to be avoided in religious rites.

Comment: Closely related giving general reason. [Why are the black colored clothes avoided when visiting temple?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/296/5212). The temple of Ashapuri Devi might have some specific reason though.

Comment: Kula Devi or Kulaswamini means Family goddess

Answer (score 0):

it is just like following culture with out thinking. Our God has given us brain to think. Only visible is truth. God absorbe everything and just one color can not change the Aura. So please dont follow things blindly. think understand and work accordingly.

Comment: The opinion based answers are strictly not allowed here because it can spark off unnecessary debates. Kindly answer with reference to authentic scriptures !